# Getting the sum from gwt table element

Tags: java, gwt

I have a table written in GWT from a List list. What i want it is to obtain the sum of a certain group of elements.

The problem with this, it is that the value I want to do the sum with its calculated, and thus not obtainable unless you calculate it before generating the List.

I was wondering if it was somehow possible to achieve this through DOM manipulation. And if so, how?.

I will show you an example:

```
DataA    DataB    DataC    DataD
---------------------------------
aaaaa    bbbbb    ccccc    12
aaaa1    bbbb1    cccc1    15
aaa11    bbb11    ccc11    17
```

I want to get the sum of "DataD" column, but i dont know how can i do it.

Thank you in advance for your time,

Kind regards,

---

Elaborate: DataD column value it is calculated and the value comes from another system and its placed into the table through a third party program; thus i cannot get its value and use it into a sum to get the value i want.

Comment: *The problem with this, it is that the value I want to do the sum with its calculated, and thus not obtainable unless you calculate it before generating the List.* - can you please elaborate this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add some event handler to the table's widget so that whenever data is added/changed in the widget, you adjust the total. Please give more information about what widgets you are using to represent the table.

EDIT:
now that we know you are using an HTMLLayoutContainer, I assume DataD is being poopulated at a place beyond your controll in code. What you can do is add event handlers to handle the add remove etc events. For example, you could do something like below:

```
    //Your container
    HtmlLayoutContainer c = new HtmlLayoutContainer(templates.getTemplate());

    c.addAddHandler(new AddEvent.AddHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onAdd(AddEvent event) {
            //Do proper exception handling, check if it is the right widget for dataD, do the needed calculations etc
            sum += Double.parseDouble(((HTML)event.getWidget()).getHTML());                
        }
    });

    c.addRemoveHandler(new RemoveEvent.RemoveHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onRemove(RemoveEvent event) {
            //handle all conditions like in onAdd in AddHandler above
            sum -= Double.parseDouble(((HTML)event.getWidget()).getHTML());
        }
    });
```

You can look into the API to see what exactl events match your needs best (http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-3.0.0/javadoc/gxt/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/container/HtmlLayoutContainer.html)

Comment: I am using HtmlLayoutContainer which is a GXT Sencha 3.0 widget.